# Do we get a more general integral if we allow countable sums in the Riemann integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

> **Question.** Suppose we take the definition of the Riemann integral by Darboux sums, and augment it by allowing countable partitions of the relevant interval, not just finite ones. Does this alter the set of functions we can integrate?

Comment: you are defining a series of integrals, so if the intervals on the partition are bounded I think that the question is moved to the convergence of the series.

Comment: How do you want to define such a thing, technically? All rational points give you a countable partition of $[0,1],$ too. You'd have to restrict the ordinal type of the partition, I'd imagine.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, yes, sorry. I should have been more specific. I was thinking that we should take a limit over countable subsets $A$ of the real line satisfying: if $a \in A$, then either $a$ is the least element of $A$, or else the set $\{b \in A : b<a\}$ has a maximum element. And similarly on the other side.

Comment: @ProfessorVector  all rational numbers cant make a partion!  since you wont be able identify two consecutive rational numbers!

Comment: @Ashkan That's why I asked for a more precise definition of "partition". In fact, you'd just need an open set (always a countable union of open intervals) $S$ with $[a,b]-S$ countable to define reasonable integral sums (infinite series, so to assume their convergence would be a strong restriction, too) to investigate their convergence.